# Azure .Net core with sql internal server error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, nuget-package-restore

I am following microsoft documentation to deploy .Net core with sql. when I go to my website the following is displayed:

> An error occurred while starting the application. .NET Core X86
>   v4.1.1.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.1.2    |
>   Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?

When I run the app on local machine there are no errors and I am able to add toDo Items. 
In my CsProj file:

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

I have seen other people with similar issue discuss a global.json file, but i do not see any and am not sure if I should create one and what exactly to put in it.

**Possibly Related info:**
When I push to azure in command line I get this error:

> warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27' was restored
>   using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259' instead of the
>   project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'. This package may
>   not be fully compatible with your project. remote:   Restore completed
>   in 269.7 ms for D:\home\site\repository\DotNetCoreSqlDb.csproj.

the deployment is successful though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add the below to the `<PropertyGroup>` element in your **DotNetCoreSqlDb.csproj**

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
```

This is because the [Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/1.0.27) is an old nuget package which does not compatible with the your project target framework which is .NET Core 1.1.

The supported framework for the Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is as below:

> Supported Platforms:
>
> - .NET Framework 4.5
> - Windows 8
> - Windows Phone 8.1
> - Windows Phone Silverlight 8
> - Portable Class Libraries

Reference: [Package Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46349/package-microsoftcomposition-1027-is-not-compatibl.html)

Comment: I no longer get that warning when I push to Azure but I still get internal server error when navigating to my website. I would not mind  using  .net core 2.0 so I don't have issues but I don't see clear documentation for it.